# Web Speech API - Speak again (reset sentence)

Tags: javascript, jquery, speech, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

i use the `webkitSpeechRecognition()` to create my own little voice recorder.

Here is a demo (**works only with chrome!**)
http://jsfiddle.net/gsu4aod2/

Say a sentence and 
1a.) if the text correct, click on the "add sentence" button
1b.) if the text not correct click the "speak again" button

My problem is that i dont know how to "reset" the text.
When i use the `stop()` and `start()` method, the text is removed but than i must confirm the access to the microphone again and again.

Any ideas?

**Web Speech API Specification**
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the events.result data starting from index 0. You need to start the `for` loop with something called `event.resultIndex`.

> **resultIndex attribute**: The resultIndex must be set to the lowest index
>   in the "results" array that has changed. [[source](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#speechreco-event)]

```
recognition.onresult = function (event) {
    //console.log(event);
      var final = "";
      var interim = "";
      for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
        if (event.results[i].final) {
          final += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        } else {
          interim += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        }
      }
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gsu4aod2/1/)